# New list created by slicing old list; modifying 'new' changes 'old' as well?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

**Summary:** *I created a new list variable by taking a slice of an original one. When I tweak the new list,  the previous one also changes, but I'm fairly certain they are two distinct lists! Here's my general method:*

1.Create initial list `all_info` by calling a function. Each list item is itself a list with 5 elements.

```
all_info = CrossReference(start_info, RBS_info, promoter_info)
```

2.Create a new list `all_info_mod` by slicing the initial list to remove the first item (I need to do this for later code). Then confirm thet are distinct.

```
all_info_mod = all_info[1:]

all_info #Shows original list
all_info_mod #Shows sliced list
```

3.Increment the first 3 elements of each outer list by 1. Then check.

```
for i in all_info_mod:
    for j in range(0, 3):
        i[j] += 1

all_info_mod #Successfully altered
all_info #Also altered?!
```

The initial list is also altered when it shouldn't be. I have tested with simpler examples and get the same result. Perhaps it's a result of my previous code that comes before this? (Can provide more details if needed).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
all_info = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [5,6,7]]
all_info_mod = all_info[1:]
```

You perform slicing on `all_info` to create a new list `all_info_mod`.
The problem is that the elements of `all_info` are (references to) lists, so `all_info_mod` will contain the copy of the references to lists. The references are copied, so at the end both lists contain references to the same lists.
This explains why when you modifies the lists referenced by the elements of `all_info_mod`, you also modify the lists referenced by the elements of `all_info`.

Note that if you modify directly an element of `all_info_mod` by assignment, i.e. if you replace the reference to a list with another one, then `all_info` is not changed:

```
all_info_mod[1] = [9,9,9]
print(all_info)      # [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]
print(all_info_mod)  # [[2, 3, 4], [9, 9, 9]]
```

If you really want to duplicate the data in another list, you have to use the method [copy.deepcopy()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html), as follows:

```
import copy
all_info = ...
all_info_mod = copy.deepcopy(all_info[1:])
```

Comment: A more approachable explanation alongside a working solution. Really useful, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should import `copy` module and make a `deepcopy` if you don't want changes in original list.

```
import copy

all_info_mod = copy.deepcopy(all_info[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you're modifying mutable objects that both lists contain references to.  Modifying the list you sliced won't change the slice, but modifying a mutable object in that list will also be visible from the other list, because both lists contain the same object.

```
list_ = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
slice_ = list_[:]
list_[0] = [7, 8, 9]
print(slice_)
# [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

list_[1].append(0)
print(slice_[1])
# [4, 5, 6, 0]

print(list_[1] is slice_[1])  # The two lists both contain the same list object
# True
```

Comment: Also upvoted because of very useful explanation - this is great for the future.